# SmoothScroll between components. VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, smooth-scrolling

So I'm trying to implement smoothscroll into my Vue.js app.

I have a SideBar.vue component that handles the the menu and navigation.

Right now I only want to implement this behaviour to the first 2 links.

Each of this links should scroll to different components that are rendered in the same page.

I've tried about 4 plugins so far, none have worked. I'm unable to properly reference a div element from another component. For example:

```
<template>
<div class="sidebar-nav">
  <div @mouseover="openSideBar" @mouseleave="closeSideBar" :class="{ 'side-menu': !opened, 'side-menu side-menu-opened': opened }" role="navigation">
    <div id="ninja" class="ninja"></div>
    <div class="menu-content">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
          <div class="menu-item first-logo" @click="goIntro">
              <span class="first-item"> Home </span>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="menu-item" @click="goPortfolio">
            <span class="second-item">Portfolio</span>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="menu-item">
            <span class="third-item"> About </span>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="menu-item">
            <span class="fourth-item"> Contact me </span>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="menu-item">
            <span class="fifth-item">Blog</span>
          </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
name: "SideBar",
data() {
  return {
    opened: false,
    options: {
      onDone: this.closeSideBar,
      onCancel: this.closeSideBar
    }
  }
},
methods: {
  openSideBar(){
    this.opened = true
  },
  closeSideBar() {
    this.opened = false
  },
  goIntro(){
    this.$scrollTo(document.getElementById("intro"), 800, this.options)
  },
  goPortfolio(){
    this.$scrollTo(document.getElementById("portfolio"), 800, this.options)
  }
}
}
</script>
```

And here's the Intro's markup just to show an example:

```
<template>
  <section id="intro">
    <div class="intro-container">
        <h1 id="intro-shuffle"> {{intro}}</h1>
        <h1 class="welcome fadein"> {{ welcome }}</h1>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>
```

Now I believe that the problem is that the SideBar component does not know about #intro and #portfolio. I've tried referencing using the ref attr, but it's scoped to its current component. I've found that it appears to be very difficult to reference global objects/elements in Vue.js.

If someone with more experience could point me to the best ways to this kind of global referencing, I would certainly appreciate it.

Here's my HomeComponent, where both intro and portfolio are rendered:

```
<template>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <app-intro></app-intro>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <hr class="neon-lights">
            <hr class="neon-lights">
            <app-portfolio></app-portfolio>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Intro from './Intro'
import Portfolio from './Portfolio'

export default {
    name: "home",
    components: {
        Intro,
        Portfolio
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Use `document.getElementById`.

Comment: Isn't there a Vue.js way to do this?

Comment: You *could* do it using an event bus, but scrolling is really outside the realm of Vue. You don't model scroll position. Because you're using element IDs, it's really a document-oriented operation.

Comment: I understand. Thank you so much!

Comment: @RoyJ tried with `document.getElementById` and now the HTMLElement is properly referenced but still no effect. Tried with https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-smoothscroll and https://github.com/rigor789/vue-scrollto no luck.

Comment: What is your code for triggering the scroll using `vue-smoothscroll`?

Comment: @RoyJ this.$scrollTo(document.getElementById("intro"), 800, this.options). Options being a simple object with an onDone and onCancel property, both pointing to the same closeSideBar function

Comment: [vue-smoothscroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-smoothscroll) uses `this.$SmoothScroll(target,duration,callback,context);`, and I think you *need* to provide `context` (which div is scrollable) in your case.

Comment: @RoyJ okay, for some reason the template I'm using was setting overflow:hidden on the html element. This was causing some kind of conflict because now it works. Thanks gor your help!